# Outlook for Mac 2011: How to find the folder where a message is stored?

Tags: ms-office

When I perform a search in Outlook for Mac 2011, I can't seem to figure out how to determine which folder each of the search results is stored.

This questions has been answered for Office for Windows: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/i-can-t-find-the-folder-where-a-message-is-stored-HA001140027.aspx

This is probably completely obvious, but I can't seem to find it...

**Update**: I'm still looking for a solution that doesn't require me to switch to View -> Reading Pane -> Below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method to show which folder an email is currently located is to right click on the header bar in Outlook and add the "folder" (visible columns have a check mark to the left of it) column to the current view. This will show you which folder said email is contained in when you perform a search. If you no longer wish to have the "folder" seen in the current view just reverse the process to hide it again. If this is your only customization to the current view you can alternately choose to "reset to defaults" by right clicking on the header bar and choosing the reset to defaults action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems like this only works when View -> Reading Pane -> Below is selected.  However, I prefer to work with View -> Reading Pane -> Right selected.  Is there any way to view a message's folder without having to switch to this reading view?

Comment: @cdwilson Not that I can readily see out of the box. It seems to be a limitation of this specific view. There might be a possibility to create a macro and then bind it to a menu button to switch between the views, but it would be a hack at best.

Comment: thanks for the help, I do really appreciate it.  I accepted your answer because it technically answers my original question and I haven't been able to find another solution that works with View -> Reading Pane -> Right

Answer (score 2):

Based on other answers, I found what seems to be (IMHO) the easiest approach: perform a search and

**select "All Items"**

in the main ribbon (menu bar). You should see a column labeled "Folder" with the location of the item. I've, personally, been searching for a better answer for some time but thanks to this post, I came up with the aforementioned solution... with one click (with Reading Pane > Right).

---

Note: If for some reason, the Folder column is NOT displayed in "All Items" view, you can right-click on the column headers and select "Folder".

Answer (score 2):

I simply double-click on the the message to open it in a new window. In the window bar or header, the folder name will follow the subject name of the message with a hyphen. In the example below, the subject is "Attached Image;" the folder is "Scanner Email."
 [image]

I will add that I recently lost a folder somewhere within all my other folders. I knew the name of the folder by doing the above after doing a search for something in that folder. But I had no idea where it went and didn't want to expand every folder to find it. So I put my cursor in the search bar, which opens up the Search tab, then clicked on Advanced> clicked on the drop down menu where "Item Contains" shows> clicked on "Folder"> since I knew the name of the folder, as I mentioned, I could select: "Folder" "Is" and when I click on the button "none", it opens a drop down menu where I can scroll down and select "Choose Folder." Once I started typing in the name of the folder, it brought it up with the full path. Hope this helps someone in the future.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange the messages by Folder. This way you see the Folder also with Reading Pane > Right. To arrange the messages: View / Arrange by / Folder. Or click on Arrange by: (top of the messages list) / Folder.

Answer (score -1):

Search ALL FOLDERS will show you the folder, even in reading pane Right!